# Вызвать скрипт еще раз из самого скрипта bash

Tags: bash

У меня есть скрипт с тремя аргументами, при попадении в определенную ветку if'a нужно вызвать этот же скрипт только с другими параметрами.
Пытался через

```
source script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
exec script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 &
```

Comment: Все три способа работают. В чём проблема?

Comment: Я вызываю скрипт в цикле и при таком способе 
source /home/user/Downloads/grab_the_photos/grab_the_photos.sh ${images_count_in_each_folder[$j]} $image_per_folder 0
попадаю в бесконечный цикл на первой итерации своего цикла

Comment: Ну значит ищите ошибку в тех условиях, которые проверяют, вызывать или не вызывать

Comment: Помогла явная передача параметров с флагами, в начале скрипта есть операция деления и делитель должен был браться из параметров скрипта, но он не видел этот параметр